# Convert callback function to promise and execute in series

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have a legacy function `callApiCallback` which takes a callback function. I have transformed it into a promise function and then call it on a set of rows returned from the database, but it is not executed sequentially and the next step of my main promise is reached before the series of callApi functions start their execution.

Code

```
var counter = 0;

function callApi(params) {  
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  counter++;
  console.log('Call API: ' + counter);

  callApiCallback(params, function (result, error) {
    if (error) {
      deferred.reject(new Error('API error'));
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(result);
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
});

callDatabase()
  .then(function (rows) {
    console.log('Start');
    return Q.allSettled(rows.map(function (row) {
      return callApi(params);
    }));
  })
  .done(function () {
    console.log('End');
  });
```

Expected Output

```
Start
1
2
...
N
End
```

Output

```
Start
End
1
2
...
N
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't you be returning, as in `return Q.allSettled(...` otherwise you're just calling `done` one the same promise as `then` ?

Comment: I missed to add it in the sample code, fixed now. Even when I return it it still has the problem I have described, so the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Don't you want to pass the `row` instead of some `params`? Also, your `'Call API: ' + counter` log seems to be never executed.

Comment: @Berg, you can't reproduce because you have to put real HTTP calls, in the sample call the `deferred` is resolved immediately, because there is no delay. I will update the sample to do a HTTP call.

Comment: Which sample? No, no, I just used a timeout instead of `callApiCallback`. Btw, you seem to have interchanged the `result, error` parameters, they don't follow node conventions.